# No animation if on same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like so that if for example click the " Fair Trade " button, and the content loads the user should not have the content loading again if the user click on the same " Fair Trade " button. Long story short, it should never load the already loaded content.

Also right now the content nicely fades in, would it be hard to make some kind of animation for example make the title ease in from the left? If you got an idea on how to make that happend i would appreciate that.

All help appreciated thanks.

```js
var $imgs = $(".section-link");


var data = [{
    title: "Fair Trade",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Toxicfree",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Quality",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Organic",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Vegan",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
];

// Get reference to the output area
var $outputDiv = $(".section-display");
var defaulttext = $outputDiv.find(".text1").html()
var defaultTitle = $outputDiv.find(".title1").html();



$imgs.on("click", function() {


  $This = $(this) ;
  
  $imgs.removeClass("clicked") ;
  $This.addClass("clicked");
    
  $(".title1", $outputDiv).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, function() {
    $(".title1", $outputDiv).html(data[$This.index() - 1].title)
      .animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
  });
  $(".text1", $outputDiv).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, function() {
    $(".text1", $outputDiv).html(data[$This.index() - 1].text)
      .animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
  })
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.section-display').length != 1 && $(e.target).closest(".section-link").length != 1) {
    $(".title1", $outputDiv).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, function() {
      $(".title1", $outputDiv).html(defaultTitle)
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
    });
    $(".text1", $outputDiv).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, function() {
      $(".text1", $outputDiv).html(defaulttext)
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        });
        $($imgs).removeClass('clicked')
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.section-link {
  width: 100px;
  
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.section-link.clicked{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 fair-d">
  <h2>
    <nobr>FAIR-TRADE</nobr>
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 toxic-d">
  <h2>TOXICFREE</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 quality-d">
  <h2>QUALITY</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 organic-d">
  <h2>ORGANIC</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 vegan-d">
  <h2>VEGAN</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-display active info-p4">
  <h2 class="title1">Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <h2 class="text1">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
  <br> Tap on the symbols if you want to know more.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `hasClass()` to determine if the clicked element already has the `.clicked` class, and if so do nothing.

Also note that you can DRY up your code by extracting the common logic out to a function, like this:

```js
var $imgs = $(".section-link");
var data = [{
    title: "Fair Trade",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Toxicfree",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Quality",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Organic",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    title: "Vegan",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
];

// Get reference to the output area
var $outputDiv = $(".section-display");
var defaultText = $outputDiv.find(".text1").html();
var defaultTitle = $outputDiv.find(".title1").html();

$imgs.on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    $imgs.removeClass('clicked');
    setItem($this.addClass('clicked').index());
  }
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.section-display').length != 1 && $(e.target).closest(".section-link").length != 1) {
    $imgs.removeClass('clicked');
    setItem();
  }
})

function setItem(index) {
  var title = index ? data[index - 1].title : defaultTitle;
  var text = index ? data[index - 1].text : defaultText;

  $outputDiv.find(".title1").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).html(title).fadeIn();
  });
  $outputDiv.find(".text1").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).html(text).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```css
.section-link {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section-link.clicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 fair-d">
  <h2>
    <nobr>FAIR-TRADE</nobr>
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 toxic-d">
  <h2>TOXICFREE</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 quality-d">
  <h2>QUALITY</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 organic-d">
  <h2>ORGANIC</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-link small-solid-circle-p4 vegan-d">
  <h2>VEGAN</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-display active info-p4">
  <h2 class="title1">Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <h2 class="text1">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br>
    <br> Tap on the symbols if you want to know more.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what i want, would it be possible to make the default text not  load if already loaded? If you press outside any of the button the default text loads even if already loaded. Thanks.

Comment: If you want that behaviour just remove the `$(document).on("click")` event handler.

Comment: Well that removed the enitre possiblity to get back to the default text, but i added  " $imgs.hasClass('clicked') " to the if statement below the document on click function and its not working  perfect, thank you for all the help!